# Displaying address of the current frame in the address bar

Tags: html, frames

I am using three frames in my html page. The top most frame gives the logos which is always constant. The bottom left frame contain links(more like an index) to different jsp pages. The links clicked in this frame are to be displayed in the bottom right frame. I want the address of the current webpage in the bottom right frame to be displayed on the address bar.
How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pile of JavaScript with [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (note [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState)) but it would be clunky at best.

I'd recommend scrapping the frames and using JSP to template the shared content into standalone pages.

Comment: :Why don't you recommend frames?

Comment: They break bookmarking, search engine linking, link sharing, printing, etc.